# Как сделать так, чтобы именно класс мог быть декоратором, а не его экземпляры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такой класс декоратор, чтобы именно он принимал на вход функцию?

Поясню. Вот сейчас у меня есть так называемый класс функтор с переопределённым методом `__call__` и его экземпляры могут быть декораторами:

```
from functools import wraps


class FuncDec:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('I am working properly')
        return wrapper

func_dec = FuncDec()

@func_dec
def func():
    print('Hello')

func()
# Hello
# I am working properly
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы я мог декорировать функцию не с помощью (или не только) `@func_dec`, а с помощью `@FuncDec`. Я не понимаю, как и что надо прописать в `__init__`, чтобы декоратором стал именно класс.

Долго рылся в инэте и нашёл почти подходящий пример и не понимаю, почему у них работает, а у меня нет...
По сути ведь разница только в том, что в примере декоратор с параметром.

```
from functools import wraps
class Repeater:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __call__(self, f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(self.n):
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
@Repeater(3)
def foo():
    print('foo')
foo()
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

примерно так:

```
class FuncDec:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('I am working properly')

@FuncDec
def func():
    print('Hello')
```

---

```
@Repeater(3)
def foo():
    print('foo')
foo()
```

можно записать так:

```
repeater = Repeater(3)# создаём экземпляр класс
foo = repeater(foo) # в foo записываем функцию wrapper
foo() # вызываем wrapper
```

а ваш начальный код так:

```
funcdec = FuncDec() # создаём экземпляр класс
foo = funcdec(foo) # в foo записываем функцию wrapper
foo() # вызываем wrapper
```

а мой код можно записать так:

```
foo = FuncDev(foo) # foo становится экземпляром класса FuncDev
foo() # вызываем __call__ нашего класса
```

в первых двух вариантах в `foo` лежит `wrapper`, а в моем варианте экземпляр класса

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! А вы бы не могли, пожалуйста, хотя бы вкратце объяснить разницу между ``` @FuncDev ```  и  ``` @FuncDev() ```  Хоть убей не понимаю.

Answer (score 4):

В `Repeater(3)` декоратор — тоже экземпляр

Так подойдёт?

```
from functools import wraps

class Repeater:
    @staticmethod
    def repeat(n):
        def inner(fn):
            @wraps(fn)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                for _ in range(n):
                    fn(*args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper
        return inner

@Repeater.repeat(3)
def foo():
    print('foo')

foo()
```

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку у вас пустой конструктор, то и декоратор вызывается с конструктором. По сути дела, у вас `func_dec = FuncDec()` заменяется обычным вызовом конструктора с собачкой:

```
@FuncDec()
def func():
    print('Hello')
```

Comment: я вот этот момент всё никак понять не могу.
Когда я ставлю @FuncDec  без кавычек, то интерпретатор ругается ругается
```  __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  ``` . А я никак не могу понять какой второй аргумент подаётся в конструктор.

Comment: @TobaSko первый это `self` а второе `func`